# Deleting object in Entity Framework by Id

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm trying to develop a simple c# MVVM CRUD application which hooks up to a SQL Server database, I'm currently having an issue deleting records of my entities
Apparently the entityId I'm searching for returns null, in which I'm pretty much sure it exists in the database, Therefore no deleting happens
I could really use you help!
thank you!

```
public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
    {
        using (MyDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            T entity = await context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.Id == id);
            context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]? Or at least error you are getting.

Comment: There is a common law in architecture that you never really delete anything, except you have to do it by law, but you update a field (a flag) call like "Is_deleted" or similar to true and then when you make a select, you filter those records with is_deleted = true

Comment: The `<T>` generic parameter in question is very ambiguous and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to await `SaveChangesAsync`, change code accordingly:

```cs
public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
{
    using (MyDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        T entity = await context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.Id == id);
        context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Otherwise the context can be disposed before the `SaveChangesAsync` make/process the db call resulting in effectively no-op (`Task` should end up with exception but it is not observed since you are not awaiting the call).